commandline tool for setting application restrictions in android app
Is there a way to set apps configuration beside the programmatic way with
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setApplicationRestrictions(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)
via a commandline tool?
Best regards
Thomas
